# How to get nth set of two rows that have the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In SQL 2005 I have a view that contains pairs of rows that have similar data (ranked by UnitID) and I need to get every 100th pair, how would I do this? I use the following query to get close to what I need but it's rank is every other number (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, etc... but would like it to be (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY UnitID)) t,
    TestID, UnitID, Passed, Title
FROM v100thCTS
) q
ORDER BY t
```

This gives me the following results:

```
t     TestID        UnitID     Title 
------------------------------------
1     203430627     18523393   Vout 1 
1     203430628     18523393   Vout 2    
3     203430729     18523403   Vout 1    
3     203430730     18523403   Vout 2    
5     203430751     18523405   Vout 1
5     203430752     18523405   Vout 2
7     203430773     18523407   Vout 1
7     203430774     18523407   Vout 2
9     203430864     18523416   Vout 1
9     203430865     18523416   Vout 2
```

I didn't iterate to 100+ records but the solution would have to apply to any number of rows greater than or less than 100.  In this case if I wanted every 2nd pair then my output would be:

```
t     TestID        UnitID     Title 
------------------------------------
3     203430729     18523403   Vout 1
3     203430730     18523403   Vout 2
7     203430773     18523407   Vout 1
7     203430774     18523407   Vout 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY UnitID) tGroup, TestID, UnitID, Title
  FROM v100thCTS
) q
WHERE tGroup % 2 = 0
```

Output:

```
| TGROUP |    TESTID |   UNITID |  TITLE |
|--------|-----------|----------|--------|
|      2 | 203430729 | 18523403 | Vout 1 |
|      2 | 203430730 | 18523403 | Vout 2 |
|      4 | 203430773 | 18523407 | Vout 1 |
|      4 | 203430774 | 18523407 | Vout 2 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cdc8/1).

Note the output has the corrected group and the output you said it was expected wasn't actually the expected one based on your requirements :)

Comment: You have me going in the right direction.  This should work if I want the 100th set, 200th set, etc.